# parsing html code and print out

Tags: php, html

ive this html page ( PART CODE) with multi ( a href="https://twitter.com/$name) 
I need to parse all $names and print in page 
how i can do this ?

```
 <td>Apr 01 2011<br><b>527
  </b> 
</td>
<td>
                                            <a href="https://twitter.com/al_rasekhoon" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show count="false" data-lang="" data-width="60px" > al_rasekhoon</a>
</td>                                   
</tr>
   <tr class="rowc"><td colspan="11"></td></tr>
```

Comment: What is a "multi"? What is a "$names"?

Comment: multi means there more than element to parse like

Comment: He means multiple a elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over your $names array and print a correct `a` tag for every entry in that array. Like this:

```
<?php foreach($names as $name){ ?>
    <a href="https://twitter.com<?php echo $name ?>"><?php echo $name ?></a>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: lets say i need to parse from page names.html how i can apply this into this code

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but that seems tricky. Better to have an array of names somewhere and use it to print the contents in names.html as well as the contents of your twitter links page.

Comment: This answer was accepted but it doesn't appear to be the solution to the OPs question.

Comment: If the OP accepted it I assume it was satisfactory. Question wasn't all that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like screen scraping, and you need to traverse the DOM for this.  REs would be very unreliable.

DOMDocument may help you, but you might want to look into a library for screen scraping, such as BeautifulSoup (or some PHP equiv).

Comment: 'you **need** to traverse the DOM' - nope, `explode`'s got you covered, no need to use an html parser for this :)

Comment: I'm not sure this would cover all your bases if you had a more generic web page with complex and nested content (or applet tag?), but for the OPs posted content it will likely work well enough.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered applet tags in my answer - but just splitting on '<a ' should make sure it just matches links. As far as I know (correct me if I should be wrong), as you can't escape '<' in html the only false positives could be in `CDATA` tags which could easily be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you fetch a html page from somewhere and want to extract all linked twitter users? You can either parse the html code or do this with a bit of string splitting. This code is untested but should give you an idea:

```
$input = '(the html code)';
$links = explode('<a ', $input); //split input by start of link tags
for ($i = 0; $i < count($links); $i++) {
    //cut off everything after the closing '>'
    $links[$i] = explode('>', $links[$i], 2)[0]
    //skip this link if it doesn't go to twitter.com
    if (strpos($links[$i], 'href="twitter.com/') === False) { continue; }
    //split by the 'href' attribute and keep everything after 'twitter.com'
    $links[$i] = explode('href="twitter.com/', $links[$i], 2)[1]
    //cut off everything after the " ending the href attribute
    $links[$i] = explode('"', $links[$i], 2)[0]
    //now $links[$i] should contain the twitter username
    echo $links[$i]
}
```

Note: if there are other links to twitter on the page that are not the main page or an user, they will get printed too (e.g. if the page links to the twitter FAQ). You would need to filter them manually.

php sucks, let's do this in python!

```
input = '(the html code)'
links = [l.split(">", 1)[0] for l in input.split("<a ")}
twitter_links = [l for l in links if 'href="twitter.com/' in l]
twitter_hrefs = [l.split('href="twitter.com/', 1)[1] for l in twitter_links]
users = [l.split('"', 1)[0] for l in twitter_hrefs]
print '\n'.join(users)
```